# How to use 'makeglossaries'?

Tags: compiling, miktex, glossaries

I try to make a glossary with the glossaries package. I understand that I have to run `makeglossaries` to display the glossary. (according to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426835/example-for-a-simple-latex-glossary): "Processing the file will have to include a call to `makeglossaries` followed by at least one more invocation of `latex`.")

How do I run `makeglossaries` on MikTeX (Win 7)?

Some guides say I should put some commandline in the makefile. What is the makefile? seriously, I've googled this, but can't find any simple explanation. Do I need to do this?

Answer (score 11):

The Perl script `makeglossaries` comes along with the `glossaries` package. It calls a backend (`makeindex` or `xindy`) to sort and typeset glossaries, lists of acronyms, lists of symbols etc. On the command line, you would simply type

```
latex mydoc
makeglossaries mydoc
latex mydoc
```

to include one or more glossaries in your document. Hence, `makeglossaries` is used similarly to the well-known `bibtex` program. Usually, LaTeX editors offer the possibility to run `latex` and `bibtex` via the menu or the toolbar. If this applies to your editor it shouldn't be a problem to configure it to interface with `makeglossaries` in the same way.

Comment: Further explenation: To run perl scripts on Windows, you need to install a perl-interpreter such as ActivePerl (http://www.activestate.com/activeperl, there is a free version). After installing it, you can use makeglossaries filename-of-tex-file to run it (as described above). You do not need a makefile. Depending on what editor you use, you can just tell the editor to run the makeglossaries script for you