# Glossaries not displaying list

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, kile

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[unicode,colorlinks=true]{hyperref} 
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries} 
\usepackage{lipsum}


\newacronym{svm}{svm}{support vector machine}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\gls{svm}


\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

It's the firs time I'm using `glossaries` and I manage to get it working but it does not print the list of acronyms.

I'm using [kile](http://kile.sourceforge.net/) and if I compile using Makeindex it says that there is no .idx file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to run `makeglossaries filename` or `makeindex.exe -s filename.ist -t filename.alg -o filename.acr filename.acn` if you want to use makeindex

Comment: ah! filename without extension! I tried all the possible ones, instead was without! thank you! I think this question can be closed, it was stupid!

Comment: IMHO, no question regarding TeX is stupid over here...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it could be resolved by omitting the file ending as described in the manual. Basically a typo.

Comment: If anybody has a dupe at hand, duping would be better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use 'makeglossaries'?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25950/how-to-use-makeglossaries)