# Glossary does not work on different platforms

Tags: glossaries

I am writing my master thesis. When I compile and run the Tex file on Ubuntu everything works fine. When I do it on OSX and Windows it return the error:

```
Package glossaries Error: Glossary entry `...' has not been defined.
```

for all the `\gls{}` entries inserted.

I do follow the procedure for makeindex from the console. (`makeindex main_body.glo -s main_body.ist -t main_body.glg -o main_body.gls`).

Any hints?
thank you in advance.

Minimal Working Example

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,bibtotoc,idxtotoc,headsepline,footsepline,
               footexclude,BCOR12mm,DIV13]{scrbook}
\input{components/info}
% include settings
\input{components/settings}
% include commands
\input{components/commands}

\makeindex
\makeglossary

\begin{document}    
    \frontmatter        
    \input{components/cover}
    \clearemptydoublepage
    \input{components/titlepage}
    \input{components/abstract}
    \tableofcontents
    \input{components/outline}
    \part[Introduction, Motivation and Backdrop]{Introduction, Motivation and Backdrop}     

    \part[Handbook and its Application]{Handbook and its Application}
    \part*{Appendix}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendix}

    \input{chapters/7_Glossary/Acronyms}
    \input{chapters/7_Glossary/Glossary}
    \glsaddall
    \printglossaries
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Glossary and Acronyms}

    \clearemptydoublepage

    \bibliography{bibliography/literature}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Try `makeglossaries main_body` in your console (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25950). Please make sure that you run LaTeX or alike before and that all needed files get created. In order to get better help, you should post an MWE here. The smalles possible example code, which yields this error for you.

Comment: Have you defined all your glossary entries in the preamble? (Or in a file that gets input in the preamble.) If you have any entries defined within the document environment, there may be an issue if you have different versions of `glossaries` installed on the different operating systems, but without a 
[minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) it's difficult to say for certain.

Comment: All the entries have been defined in the document with two input files. On the Ubuntu platform it works in this way. Moving the entries in the preamble made the tex file working also on windows. Do you know which can be the reason why? (However, Thank you for the help)

Comment: See [Drawbacks With Defining Entries in the Document Environment](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:docdefs) in the user manual.

Comment: @boletusatanas Are you using any IDE for any of the OS's?

Comment: @pushpen.paul what does it mean "IDE"?

Comment: @boletusatanas Integrated Development Environment. This term is widely used in Java, C++ etc. languages. *In latex, perhaps everybody uses the term latex editor.* :-(

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with the platform. The difference is due to using different versions of the `glossaries` package. You are basically using an entry before it's been defined. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\gls{sample}

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}
\printglossary

\end{document}
```

The first time you compile this document, you get the error:

```
! Package glossaries Error: Glossary entry `sample' has not been defined.
```

With old (pre 3.08a) versions of `glossaries`, you will *always* get this error whenever you try to use an entry before it's been defined. With newer versions of `glossaries`, you'll get the error on the first LaTeX run, but not on subsequent runs (unless you delete the `.glsdefs` file). Therefore, I suspect that your Ubuntu platform has a fairly new version of `glossaries`, which is why it seems to work, whereas your other platform has an older pre-3.08a version, which is why it doesn't work.

The simplest, and [recommended](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec%3adocdefs), solution is to define all your entries in the preamble.